# How to find a content of any file in UNIX base system

Tags: command-line

My website is hacked and now my `.htaccess` is being modify to redirect my traffic to their website I been struggling for 24 hours to resolve this problem, but still I can't find any suspect file on my server.

In my Mac Xserver we have 5 website and all of them is affected by this problem.

So I thought if I can use any command in terminal to find the URL of the site in .htaccess to find the file that is actually doing that modification.

I remember when I took UNIX/Linux course we have command `grep` but I don't know I tried to find but no result.

Please if anyone can help me find the way.

I've changed my FTP user password. Also I have changed the server login password and still no luck.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may likely have to look in several locations.  The top directory of the web servers installation directory (could be `/var/www/htdocs`); if you are using Apache HTTPD, then you can look at the `DocumentRoot` value in the httpd.conf file.

If you know that it is the `.htaccess` file, then you can use `find` to look for all of them:

```
nice find / -name .htaccess -print
```

This will start at the root directory (`/`), looking for files named `.htaccess` and display the filename to standard output (stdout).

If you know the domain name that the your site is redirecting to, then you can search the contents with `xargs` and `grep`.

```
sudo nice find / -name .htaccess -print0 | xargs -r0 fgrep -H badwolf
```

The output from `find` is change to terminate by null characters (ASCII value of zero) between each filename found.  This is sent to `xarg -r -0` takes the null-terminated list of files as input and builds up arguments to be given to `grep -FH badwolf` (or whatever the errant domain name is.  The `-FH` argument to `grep` says to search for a fixed string (not a pattern) and to always include the filename in the output.  Since some of these may not be in areas accessible to you, it's better to run this through `sudo`.

This will search your entire system, so it may take some time.

Comment: `xargs: illegal option -- r` I'm getting this

Comment: You can try just the `-0` argument.  If that doesn't work, then try: `sudo nice find / -name .htaccess -print | while read filename; do fgrep -H badwolf "$filename"; done`, which is functionally equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

It's:

```
fs "file.*" | file content | filter "content inside"
```

When you do:

```
npm install nixar
```

Source / Docs: http://nixar.work/doc

Comment: Your link is broken (it returns a blank page).